# Textarea background-position fixed problem

Tags: css

I've been searching for a solution for a few hours now, but nothing seems to work.

I have this `<textarea>` with some text and a scroll bar on the right.

```
<textarea rows="1" style="background: url(http://i35.tinypic.com/4tlkci.jpg) fixed no-repeat;">
```

The problem is that the background image scrolls with the scroll, when it should stay fixed. Safari and Firefox seem to fail on this one.

Maybe someone could show me the right way to use this or maybe post some example where the background image stays FIXED while you scroll.

Is using a background image for a textarea is considered being a bad example?

Comment: If it looks good, is easy to use, and doesn't confuse users, it's ok.

Comment: What OS/browser version are you seeing failure on?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work on all browsers I try on:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4TCP/

If all else fails, you can always make it transparent and put it over a `div`:

```
<div style="background: url(http://i35.tinypic.com/4tlkci.jpg) fixed no-repeat;">
    <textarea rows="1" style="background: transparent"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The link you gave me shows a background image in textarea, but if I type a few lines of text and scroll down, the image stays the same.
I want it to move up while I scroll down. My browser is Firefox

Comment: I have MAC OS X 10.6. Also safari browser shows the same as Firefox

Comment: Ah, then I think you are out of luck.  IE incorrectly scrolls background images in textareas with some settings.  According the the CSS 2.1 spec, the background should not scroll with a text input.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment

Comment: BTW, "fixed" generally means that an element does NOT move when the viewport changes.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was confused since I haven't seen any examples. Well then thank you for your time

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe this can be done another way?  Is it simply for looks, or does it serve a purpose?

Comment: Actually I have a <select multiple> tag with a background image.
Heres a pic: http://l6.imghost.us/9Xo/a.png
So now whenever I scroll down the background image does not move up with the text. And I get this effect: http://l6.imghost.us/2ca/b.png
I want it to scroll with the text. So that each line stays with the same background color

Comment: I've posted a new question related to my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382793/select-multiple-with-background-image