# Select multiple with background image

Tags: html, css

Alright here's the deal. I have a `<select multiple>` tag with a background image. 
So now whenever I scroll down, the background image does not move up with the text. And I get this effect:

[image: http://l6.imghost.us/SEh/c.png]

The left pic is before and the right is after I scroll

I want it to move up when I scroll down. So that each line stays with the same color.

Any suggestions on how do I do that?

Comment: Can you please add some markup that you have, that box.

Comment: My question has been answered. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but wouldn't it be more desirable to give each `option` an individual background colour instead?

[Primitive JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/)

The background image approach is bound to fail e.g. if the user increases the font size.

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly apply background colors for each row?

```
<option style="background-color: #FFF">...</option>
<option style="background-color: #EEE">...</option>
```

This works just fine (use css classes instead of the style attribute)

Comment: Maybe he get's that from a DB.

Comment: Yes I get that from a DB, and I generate the code with JS, so I'll write a function for the odd, even option background-color

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works on `select` elements, but possibly:

```
option:nth-child(odd) {
    Background-color: #ffa;
 }
```

Or, with jQuery (for less compliant/modern browsers):

```
$('option:nth-child(odd)').css('background-color','#ffa');
```

Using a background-image for the `select` to simulate zebra-striping is unlikely to work reliably across different browsers, font-sizes, platforms...

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely try this one!

Comment: @raf48: bear in mind that the pure CSS approach may not be reliable across all browsers (specifically IE < 9, or *maybe* 8, I'm not sure). The jQuery will apply in-line styles, though, so will work (though you could [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) in place of `css()`, if you'd rather.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using jquery's odd or even selectors.

For example if you have an `<ul> </ul>`

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Bla bla</li>
    <li>Bla bla 2</li>
    <li>Bla bla 3</li>
    <li>Bla bla 4</li>
    <li>Bla bla 5</li>
</ul>

$('#list li:odd').addClass('odd');
```

This will add a `class="odd"` to the li elements like this (2, 4, 6, 8, 10 etc.)
Then you can style the .odd class as you wish.